# Custom property in liquibase (after migration to newer version) causes failure in Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, liquibase

I had to migrate to the newer version of Liquibase core in Spring-boot maven project and after that, I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

**Definition of properties:**

```
<property dbms="db2,derby,mysql,h2,mssql" name="autoid" value="BIGINT"/>
<property dbms="oracle" name="autoid" value="BIGINT" />
<property dbms="postgresql" name="autoid" value="SERIAL"/>
```

**Exception thrown**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/unymira/kfirst/application/config/DatabaseManagementConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at com.unymira.kfirst.application.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at liquibase.datatype.DataTypeFactory.fromDescription(DataTypeFactory.java:251)
    at liquibase.change.core.CreateTableChange.generateStatements(CreateTableChange.java:70)
    at liquibase.change.AbstractChange.generateStatementsVolatile(AbstractChange.java:287)
    at liquibase.change.AbstractChange.warn(AbstractChange.java:358)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:110)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:284)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:198)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

**Example of property use**

```
<column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="${autoid}">
<constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="${db_prefix}instancepk" />
</column>
```

I have to mention that this code is here from the former times and  doesn't have any problems with older liquibase.

Does anybody have a suggestion about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. Would you mind submitting a more detailed bug report (including the older version number and the newer version number) at https://liquibase.jira.com/ ?

Comment: Hi @SteveDonie, thanks for the answer. I'm about to create a Jira issue for it where everything is specified. I did some more debugging there and found that the problem occurs only on MySQL (MariaDB) database. We tried to initialize the same db schema on H2, MSSQL, Postgres and didn't get any error there.

Comment: @SteveDonie JIRA Task created - https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3546

Comment: don't you have more than one datasource ?

Comment: @Eric no, only one.

Comment: I have hit the same issue. I have a set of custom properties that cause unit tests to fail during warmup.

<property name="json_type" value="json" dbms="postgresql"/>
<property name="long_text" value="text" dbms="postgresql"/>

Comment: @Taspina I have the same scenario. The above happens when I run the tests. The test db is an h2 database

Comment: @florin I think there's a bug in liquibase. See SteveDonie reply. There is a workaround. You can declare a test schema on your test resources and use native types supported by your DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a not very elegant **workaround** whilst this bug is open.

***Disclaimer:*** This will add a slight overhead to your tests and might not suit everyone. You will need to maintain your test schema up to date manually.

Given you have the following DB on you liquibase migration step:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  name text not null,
  hobbies text[] not null,
  locals jsonb,
  status boolean not null default false,
  date_time_updated timestamp,
  date_time_created timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

On your test/resources in your SpringBoot rest resources you can create a testschema.sql with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  id character varying(255) DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  hobbies ARRAY NOT NULL,
  locals json NOT NULL,
  status boolean,
  date_time_updated timestamp without time zone,
  date_time_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

The hobbies is a:

```
<property name="json_type" value="json" dbms="postgresql"/>
```

And my in my entity I have

```
@Table(name = "foo")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@TypeDef(
  name = "string-array",
  typeClass = StringArrayType.class
)
public class Foo {
...
@Type(type = "string-array")
@Column(name = "hobbies", columnDefinition = "text[]")
private String[] hobbies;

@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "locals", columnDefinition = "json")
private JsonNode locals;
```

Then you can simply write a @DataJpaTest for you repo like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
  "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate"
})
public class TestFooRepository {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;
  @Autowired
  private FooRepository fooRepository;

  @Test
  void injectedComponentsAreNotNull() {
    assertThat(dataSource).isNotNull();
    assertThat(jdbcTemplate).isNotNull();
    assertThat(entityManager).isNotNull();
    assertThat(notificationRepository).isNotNull();
  }

  @Test
  public void testShouldSaveTheCorrectObject() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Foo expected = buildTestFoo();
    fooRepository.save(expected);
    final Optional<Foo> actual = notificationRepository.findById("<foo_id>");
    Assert.assertNotNull(actual);
    Assert.assertTrue(actual.isPresent());

    Assert.assertEquals(expected.getId(), actual.get().getId());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened because starting from 3.6.0, I have to use `dbms="mariadb"` when running on MariaDB, whereas it used to be identified as `"mysql"` in prior versions.

Caused by this change: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/7fb10ed7ae599cab585d4a6a4ec891ad7b91ecf1#diff-a07fbaf7b19fd286fef2e684648d5159

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the Open JDK 11. After switching to Oracle JDK 11, liquibase:diff runs ok. Weird.